# Killing a process in windows with a php call

Tags: php, windows, kill

I want to kill a process using php with `exec` function in windows. Usually what I do is `TASKKILL /S system /F /IM program.exe`

But when I execute this thorough php, it always shows access denied. But I can execute the same with cmd (run as admin). Is there any way to kill the process. I don't mind security issues. Just want a solution.

Comment: I think you should run apache with admin rights.

Comment: did php / apache run under user Admin?

Comment: Indeed, in order this to work you would need to run Apache with administration privileges, but this is `A Very Bad Thing ™`

Comment: Do you run Apache as service? Are you asking how to change the user a Windows service uses?

Comment: +1 to - s3v3n - @mailer what are you trying to do?

Comment: You could do it quite safely if apache started the task, you would need a means to start services from apache.

Comment: I had the same issue, I tried to run wamp as administrator, but when i take task manager it seems like the user is not administrator. Moreover is there any way by which we could set the user of apache as admin in httpd.conf?